# $http.jsonp for wikipedia doesnt work

Tags: ajax, angularjs, jsonp, mediawiki

I have a small project in jQuery that calls wikipedia API by jsonp technique. 
here is the snippet of codes in jQuery:

```
    // load wikipedia data
var wikiUrl = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=' + cityStr + '&format=json&callback=wikiCallback';
var wikiRequestTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $wikiElem.text("failed to get wikipedia resources");
}, 8000);

$.ajax({
    url: wikiUrl,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "callback",
    success: function( response ) {
        var articleList = response[1];

        for (var i = 0; i < articleList.length; i++) {
            articleStr = articleList[i];
            var url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + articleStr;
            $wikiElem.append('<li><a href="' + url + '">' + articleStr + '</a></li>');
        };

        clearTimeout(wikiRequestTimeout);
    }
});
```

I am trying to convert to $http.jsonp in AngularJS, and here is the snippet of codes that is trying to get a same result:

```
            var wikiUrl = appSettings.wiki + $scope.address.city + '&format=json&callback=wikiCallback';

        $http.jsonp(wikiUrl).success(function(res){
            console.log(res);

        }).error(function(){
            console.log('Wrong entry for Wikipedia!');
        });
```

but it cat get anything and I have the following error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: wikiCallback is not defined

Please help.

Comment: look in `$http.jsonp` docs...you aren't specifying callback properly

Comment: @charlietfl: Thanks changing callback from wikicallback to JSON_CALLBACK solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular expects you to define JSONP callback function name as `JSON_CALLBACK`. So your code should be:

```
var wikiUrl = appSettings.wiki + $scope.address.city + '&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
```

Reference: [$http.jsonp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp).